# Laravel Eloquent: SUM category products using SQL query (Morph to Many)

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-7

**Brief**

Sum parent category subcategories related products and add a custom column (e.g `products_count`) to the parent category.

---

**Migrations**

Categories

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('category_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Products

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('price');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Categorizables

```
Schema::create('categorizables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->uuidMorphs('categorizable');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Models**

Category

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Product::class, 'categorizable');
}
```

Product

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categorizable');
}
```

**What I tried?**

Category Model

```
public function getCountProductsAttribute()
{
    if(!$this->category_id) {
        $sum = 0;

        collect($this->subcategories->loadCount('products'))->each(function($category) use(&$sum) {
            $sum+=$category->products_count;
        });

        return $sum;
    }
}
```

This will be count parent category subcategories products and return the sum to the category which is the parent category.

How to sum parent category subcategories products on the query process with eloquent without using mutators as me?

Comment: Can you try to explain "Each products can be attached only to child categories. How I can get sum of parent category products by there child category products?" in more detail? I am a little confused.

Comment: My point is that each product can only belong to child categories. And I need to count the number of products of a certain parent category using its child categories @KurtFriars

Comment: I am still unclear what "each product can only belong to child categories" and "I need to count the number of products of a certain parent category using its child categories" means. Can you please show us the tables involved and the relevant keys/columns on those tables please. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on the requirement that subcategories can have subcategories we need a recursive solution. You could do as follows:

```
public function getCountProductsAttribute()
{
    if (! $this->relationLoaded('subcategories.products') {
        $this->load('subcategories.products');
    }
    
    if ($this->subcategories->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->products->count();
    }

    return $this->subcategories->reduce(function ($sum, $sub) {
        $sum += $sub->countProducts;
        return $sum;
    }, $this->products->count());
}
```

Now to get the "products_count" added on the result of a query, we can [append](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) it at runtime like so:

```
    $category = Category::find($id)->append('countProducts');
```

The append will of course only be present when the results are serialized (ie. toArray or toJson).